# Flutter, How to update a text in an item in listview after updating the content from it's detail view?

Tags: flutter

I am following this link, 
https://medium.com/…/developing-for-multiple-screen-sizes-a…
to create a master detail ipad application.
I have a scenario, there is a text field and button in detail page. When i change the text field value and press the button, the listview item (in left side) at that specific index also should be updated. can somebody suggest a work around?

Answer (score 2):

You can return the edited object using `Navigator.pop(context,object)` to the `Navigator.push()` caller. I wrote an example app for you.

the data class:

```dart
class Item {
  final String name;
  Item(this.name);
}
```

the home page, where I display the item:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Item item = Item('ali2236');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(item.name),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('edit'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return ItemEditingPage(
                      item: item,
                      callbackFunction: (editedItem){
                        setState(() {
                          item = editedItem;
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  }));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the editing page:

```dart
class ItemEditingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;
  final void Function(Item item) callbackFunction;

  const ItemEditingPage({Key key, this.item, this.callbackFunction}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemEditingPageState createState() => _ItemEditingPageState();
}

class _ItemEditingPageState extends State<ItemEditingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text('change name to aligator'),
            onPressed: () {
              ///
              /// if the name is [final], you create a new Item and pass it back
              ///
              Item item = Item('aligator');
              widget.callbackFunction(item);

              ///
              /// if the name is not final you can just change it on the current object
              ///
              //widget.item.name = 'aligator';
              //widget.callbackFunction(widget.item);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

edit: used a callback function instead of `Navigator.pop()` to notify the showcase page.

Comment: Great, This is ok for the normal (mobile) application. But in the example I mentioned is a different approach. For the tablet, items and details are shown on the same page.  so 'Navigator.pop' will destroy the entire screen.
I am looking something like Callbacks/Interface methods in Android or Delegates/Protocols in IOS.

Comment: In dart you can just pass functions as parameters and call them wen you're done.

Comment: @MUHAMMEDIQBALPA, I edited my answer to use a callback function.